# How to obtain the primitive unit cell from the new materials project website?

Tags: materials-project

I might be missing something obvious, but I am unable to find the option to download the primitive unit cell from the new materials project website.
All the options given by the export button give the conventional cell only.

[image]

Is the option to download primitive unit cell still available, or has it been removed completely?

Comment: Somehow they didn't fix this issue. you can still use old website https://legacy.materialsproject.org/

Comment: Thanks @Pranavkumar

Comment: For questions related to the Materials Project, I strongly recommend using the official forum. You will have a better chance of getting your questions answered there: https://matsci.org/c/materials-project/8

Comment: @AndrewRosen I have already thread on matsci, interesting there is no answer yet. https://matsci.org/t/unable-to-download-primitive-unit-cell-for-example-al/45383

Comment: @AndrewRosen the question was answered here within two days. The same question was asked on that forum at around the same time, and the asker received the same answer, but it took 13 days (11 days longer). The person that wrote that answer there, might have even found it **here**, since it was here first. It doesn't look like the chances of getting an answer are better there. Based on this experience alone, it looks like whoever developed this new version of the website, isn't very active on that forum (or this one).

Comment: We do help advertise that forum though: https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/265/5, https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110288/physical-properties-of-materials. My hope is that there can be a single place in which everyone can quickly and reliably get their answers. Hopefully this is on its way to becoming that place for matter modeling questions. Or maybe there can be two places: this one for people who prefer SE, and that one for people who prefer Discourse, but I don't want to sign up for 100 different forums. Two (or one) is much better!

Comment: That is the *official* Materials Project forum for questions about the Materials Project, run by Materials Project staff. Sadly, we are limited in number but that is nonetheless the official platform for such questions. Nobody has to ask questions there, but it's the only place you can guarantee Materials Project staff will be reading posts, even if turnaround times are limited...

Comment: Perhaps the Materials Project staff need to switch what they consider to be the "official" place to ask questions, since none of the people that are "guaranteed" to have read the question, knew enough about Materials Project to be able to answer this question. The MMSE community answered it within two days.

Answer (score 1):

Two people so far have said that the [legacy website](https://legacy.materialsproject.org/) was the only way that they could accomplish the task described in your question: Pranav Kumar [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/9938/how-to-obtain-the-primitive-unit-cell-from-the-new-materials-project-website#comment21063_9938) and Bin Liu [here](https://matsci.org/t/unable-to-download-primitive-unit-cell-for-example-al/45383). No comment about this has been made on the "official" Materials Project forum either, in over 6 months (see the thread with the answer by Bin Liu). Based on all of that, it seems safe to assume that the answer to your question:

> "Is the option to download primitive unit cell still available, or has it been removed completely?"

is that the option is not available in the new website, and it has indeed been removed completely, but fortunately it is still available in the legacy website. If it becomes available on the new website, hopefully someone updates this answer or writes a better answer! In that case I can even make this answer a [Community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/391772).